# How to fix Cannot find preset schema for namespace: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9

Tags: xml

```xml
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

> ==Schema Error: Cannot find preset schema for namespace: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9.

Comment: Uggh. I have the same issue as well, and I have tried a few variants... no luck, though